# Вывод массивов

Tags: массивы, php

Есть 4 инпута
index.php

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="name[1]">
          <input type="text" name="name[2]">
          <input type="text" name="surname[1]">
          <input type="text" name="surname[2]">
</form>
```

обработчик post.php в него я передаю 4 элемента в массивы $_POST и использую цикл "переберем все значения".

```
$n = count($_POST['name']);

$key = array_keys($_POST['name']);

for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++){
    echo $_POST['name'][$key[$i]]."<br>";

}
```

Элементы в массиве `$_POST['name']` выводятся отлично, а как сделать чтобы выводились и элементы в массиве  `$_POST['surname']` ?

Пример:

```
<input type="text" name="Вася">
<input type="text" name="Петя">
<input type="text" name="Иванов">
<input type="text" name="Петров">
```

при обработке должно получиться

```
Имя - Вася, Фамилия - Иванов
Имя - Петя, Фамилия - Петров
```

Подскажите???

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$array = array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'surname' => $_POST['surname']);

//print_r($array);

foreach($array['name'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo 'Имя - ', $value, ', Фамилия - ', $array['surname'][$key], '<br />';
}

?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name[]" Value="John" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" Value="Billie" />
<input type="text" name="surname[]" Value="Doe" />
<input type="text" name="surname[]" Value="Joe" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сомнительный перебор и сомнительная форма.

Для организации «переберем все значения» лучше воспользоваться оператором `foreach`, как сделал тов. [[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)](/users/3526/palmervan). Но в твоем случае, действительно, лучше перестраховаться от, к примеру, такой ситуации:

```
<input type="text" name="name[1]">
<input type="text" name="name[3]">
<input type="text" name="surname[1]">
<input type="text" name="surname[2]">
<input type="text" name="surname[999]">
```

Перестраховаться можно вот так:

```
<?

$_POST = array(
    'name' => array(
        1 => 'Первый',
        3 => 'Третий',
        ),
    'surname' => array(
        1 => 'Первый',
        2 => 'Второй',
        999 => '999-й',
        ),
    );

$keys_name = array_keys($_POST['name']);         // получаем нормальный массив [1,3]
$keys_surname = array_keys($_POST['surname']);   // и массив [1,2,999]

$keys = array_merge($keys_name, $keys_surname);  // [1,3,1,2,999]
$keys = array_unique($keys);  // убираем дубликаты: [1,3,2,999]

$n = count($keys);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
    $key = $keys[$i];

    echo 'Имя: ';
    if ($_POST['name'][$key])
        echo $_POST['name'][$key];
    else
        echo '<i>не указано</i>';
    echo ', фамилия: ';
    if ($_POST['surname'][$key])
        echo $_POST['surname'][$key];
    else
        echo '<i>не указано</i>';

    echo '<br>';
    }

?>
```

Но форму я бы организовал как-то так (если, конечно, нет каких-то особых причин):

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="person[1][name]">
      <input type="text" name="person[2][name]">
      <input type="text" name="person[1][name][surname]">
      <input type="text" name="person[2][name][surname]">
</form>
```

Тогда весь вышеприведенный PHP-код можно было бы заменить этим:

```
<?

foreach ($_POST['person'] as $person)
    {
    //if (!is_array($person)) continue;

    echo 'Имя: ';
    if ($person['name'])
        echo $person['name'];
    else
        echo '<i>не указано</i>';
    echo ', фамилия: ';
    if ($person['surname'])
        echo $person['surname'];
    else
        echo '<i>не указано</i>';

    echo '<br>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: ваш вариант супер, а как теперь загнать массив в БД MYSQL?

Comment: 1. [Подключиться к базе](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)
 2. Составить строку SQL-запроса ([INSERT INTO...](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp))
 3. [Выполнить этот запрос](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)